# (new Array(276959)).toString() results in commas

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

whenever I try to print an Array I get a lot of , and Chrome (my preferred browser) chokes the CPU.

How does it come, that it cannot print a simple Array to a string?

Comment: `new Array(276959)`, creates an array with `276959` elements, ***NOT*** an array with one value (`276959`)!  `.toString()` on arrays is the same as `.join(',')`.  This is the expected output.  If you want an array with one value, use: `[276959]`.  `new Array` is usually *not* want what you want.

Comment: Yes.. that constructor creates an array with 276k elements .. what is it you want?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: If you wanted an array with one item, you probably meant to use `[276959]`. This is a perfect example of why not to use the `Array` constructor and just stick with literals

Comment: According to the EMCAScript spec, you're using the [`new Array (len)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.2) constructor, not the [`new Array ( [ item0 [ , item1 [ , … ] ] ] )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.2.1) constructor. ("*This description applies if and only if the Array constructor is given **no arguments** or **at least two arguments**.*" -- You're providing exactly one argument.)

Comment: thanks, that is kind of a stupid mistake. Thanks for helping me out guys! That answer is simple.

Comment: @apsillers True, but the important thing to note is that the **one argument** is a `Number`. If it were a string or anything else, this wouldn't happen. Gotta love the confusion the constructor creates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toString()` prints all values in the array from the first to the last values in order, separating each one by a comma.

`new Array(276959)` defines an array with **276959 empty entries**, so the array itself has no values; it just has 276959 placeholders. When you use `.toString()`, there are no values to output, but the commas will still appear since the array has 276959 placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

When you make

```
new Array(276959)
```

you are actually creating an array of 276959 values.

Since it doesn't have any content, each value is empty, so you only see the commas (separators) when you try to print it.